# Huge performance difference: PowerShell Core vs. 5.1

Tags: performance, powershell, .net-core

Recently I have answered [another question about performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221072/88771). A solution found using *PowerShell-ISE* successfully, and good speed testified using *PowerShell Core*.

However, running the same script(s) in *PowerShell 5.1* displays utterly different results, **absolutely worse** in the performance improvement. Moreover, the original script runs *more than 4× slower* than in *ISE*.

So my question is: **where lays a reason** for such an enormous variance, and what should I avoid in PowerShell scripting (or, conversely, maybe explicitly load a .NET library or something alike)?

**PowerShell-ISE**: performance improvement cca `10:1` (**good**):

```
.\cr\122635wrapper.ps1 -maxLoop 8;$Host.Name;$PSVersionTable
```

> ```
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{0}2{1}3{2}4{3}5{4}6{5}7"
> orig.     7       269       756        19,574412
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{5}2{4}3{3}4{2}5{1}6{0}7"
> answer    7       284       839         1,911312
>
> Windows PowerShell ISE Host
>
> Name                      Value                  
> ----                      -----                  
> PSVersion                 5.1.17763.503          
> PSEdition                 Desktop                
> PSCompatibleVersions      {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion              10.0.17763.503         
> CLRVersion                4.0.30319.42000        
> WSManStackVersion         3.0                    
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3                    
> SerializationVersion      1.1.0.1
> ```

**PowerShell Core**: performance improvement cca `28:1` (**excellent**):

```
pwsh -noprofile -command .\cr\122635wrapper.ps1 -maxLoop 8;$Host.Name;$PSVersionTable
```

> ```
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{0}2{1}3{2}4{3}5{4}6{5}7"
> orig.     7       269       756       22,0310531
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{5}2{4}3{3}4{2}5{1}6{0}7"
> answer    7       284       839        0,7800336
>
> ConsoleHost
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> PSVersion                      6.2.0
> PSEdition                      Core
> GitCommitId                    6.2.0
> OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763
> Platform                       Win32NT
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> ```

**PowerShell 5.1**: performance improvement cca `4:3` (**very poor**):

```
powershell -noprofile -command .\cr\122635wrapper.ps1 -maxLoop 8;$Host.Name;$PSVersionTable
```

> ```
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{0}2{1}3{2}4{3}5{4}6{5}7"
> orig.     7       269       756       87,1714765
> VERBOSE: maxRange=7, lowCountThreshold=1, operators="+-*/"
> permutations=4096 formatString="1{5}2{4}3{3}4{2}5{1}6{0}7"
> answer    7       284       839        64,888286
>
> ConsoleHost
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503
> PSEdition                      Desktop
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.503
> CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
> ```

### Edit

Included code snippets [from the link to another question about performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221072/88771):

**122635answer.ps1** script:

```
# [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)] # slows script execution cca 50%
param (     # Variables
    [parameter()]                  # [ValidateRange(3,20)] # ???
    [int]$maxRange = 9,
    [parameter()]
    [int]$lowCountThreshold = 5,
    [parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$opString = '+-*/'     # Mathematical Operators as string
)
Begin {
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    # cast $operators variable as an array of characters
    $operators = [char[]]$opString
    $opsCount  = $operators.Count
    # Define the number range for calculations. 13 would make for the largest values 13!. Cap the script as 13
    $maxRangeMinus1 = $maxRange - 1
    # Build an array for extending 
    $maxOpsArray = 1..$maxRange
    for ( $i=0; $i -lt $maxRange; $i++ ) {
        $maxOpsArray[$maxRangeMinus1 -$i] = ,$operators[0] * $i
    }
    # Build the format string that will be used for invoking.
    # Will look like 1{2}2{1}3{0}4. Acting as place holders for mathematic operators
    [string]$formatString = -join (1..($maxRangeMinus1) | 
        ForEach-Object{"$_{$([int]$maxRangeMinus1 - $_)}"}) + $maxRange # reverse order
      # ForEach-Object{"$_{$([int]$_ - 1)}"}) + $maxRange  # $range[-1] # ascending order
      # ascending order would require `[array]::Reverse($newOperatorArr)` below in the process loop
    if ( $maxRange -gt 11 ) {
        # force decimal computing in following `$DataTable.Compute( $mathString, '')`
        $formatString = $formatString.Replace('{','.0{') + '.0'
    }
    # Determine the number of possible permutations of those operators inbetween the number set. 
    [int64]$permutations = [System.Math]::Pow($opsCount, $maxRangeMinus1)
    # Narrow down $alphanumerics array size to necessary count
    $alphanumerics = $([char[]]'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                      )[0..($opsCount -1)]
    Write-Verbose -Verbose -Message `
      ("maxRange=$maxRange, lowCountThreshold=$lowCountThreshold, operators=""$(-join $operators)""" `
     + "`r`npermutations=$permutations formatString=""$formatString""")
    $DataTable=[System.Data.DataTable]::new()
    $Error.Clear()                             # for debugging purposes
}
Process {
# Cycle each permutation. Use `for` loop instead of `0..($permutations - 1) | ForEach-Object`
$( for ( $i=0; $i -lt $permutations; $i++ ) {
    # Build an array of operators:
    #        ( based on the number converted to base `$opsCount` )
        $Number = $i
        $newOperatorArr = @( $( do {
            $Remainder = $Number % $opsCount
            # Get the associated character
            $operators[$Remainder]
            $Number = ($Number - $Remainder) / $opsCount
        } while ($Number -gt 0) ))
        # Extend array of operators to appropriate length if necessary
        if ( $newOperatorArr.Count -lt $maxRangeMinus1 ) {
            $newOperatorArr += $maxOpsArray[$newOperatorArr.Count]
        }
    ### [array]::Reverse($newOperatorArr) # only if `$formatString` is in ascending order
    $mathString = $formatString -f @( $newOperatorArr )
    # evaluate math expression using the Compute method of the DataTable class
    #                          rather than time consuming Invoke-Expression
    $value122635 = $DataTable.Compute( $mathString, '')
    # Effectively reduce the output size in advance: refuse "non-integers"
    if ( $value122635 -eq [System.Math]::Floor($value122635) ) {
        # Build an object that contains the result and the mathematical expression 
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Expression = $mathString
            Value      = [System.Math]::Floor($value122635) # [int64]$value122635
        }
    }
    # Since this take a while try and give the user some semblance of progress.
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing mathematical calculations" `
        -Status "Please wait." -PercentComplete (100 * $i / $permutations) `
        -CurrentOperation "$([math]::Round(100 * $i / $permutations))% Completed."
    # Only give group results
} ) | Group-Object Value |
      Where-Object{$_.Count -ge $lowCountThreshold} |
       Sort-Object -property Count <# -Descending <##>, @{Expression = {[int]$_.Name} }
```

**`122635wrapper.ps1` script**:

```
param (
    [parameter()]                  
    [ValidateRange(8,13)]
    [int]$maxLoop = 12
)

$y = (Measure-Command {$x = D:\PShell\CR\122635.ps1}).TotalSeconds
$z = ($x | Measure-Object -Property  Count -Sum).Sum
'orig.  {0,4} {1,9} {2,9} {3,16}' -f 7, $x.count, $z, $y

for ( $icnt=7; $icnt -lt $maxLoop; $icnt++ ) { 
    $y = (Measure-Command {
        $x = D:\PShell\CR\122635answer.ps1 -maxRange $icnt -lowCountThreshold 1
                          }).TotalSeconds
    $z = ($x | Measure-Object -Property  Count -Sum).Sum
    'answer {0,4} {1,9} {2,9} {3,16}' -f $icnt, $x.count, $z, $y
    if ($icnt -eq 7) {''}
}
```

**The original `122635.ps1` script**:

```
function ConvertTo-Base
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="Base10 Integer number to convert to another base")]
        [int]$Number=1000,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateRange(2,20)]
        [int]$Base
    )
    [char[]]$alphanumerics = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    do
    {
        # Determine the remainder
        $Remainder = ($Number % $Base)
        # Get the associated character and add it to the beginning of the string.
        $newBaseValue = "$($alphanumerics[$Remainder])$newBaseValue"
        # Adjust the number to remove the calculated portion
        $Number = ($Number - $Remainder) / $Base
        # Loop until we have processed the whole number
    } while ($Number -gt 0)

    return $newBaseValue
}

# Variables
$maxRange = 3                  #13 would make for the largest values 13!. Cap the script as 13
$lowCountThreshold = 1         # Only show group results where the match exists more than five times. 

# Mathematical Operators 
[char[]]$operators = "+-*/"

# Define the number range for calculations. 13 would make for the largest values 13!. Cap the script as 13
$range = 1..$maxRange

# Build the format string that will be used for invoking. Will look like 1{0}2{1}3. Acting as place holders for mathematic operators
$formatString = -join (1..($range.count - 1) | ForEach-Object{"$_{$([int]$_ - 1)}"}) + $range[-1]

# Determine the number of possible permutations of those operators inbetween the number set. 
$permutations = [System.Math]::Pow($operators.Count,$range.count - 1)

# Cycle each permutation
0..($permutations - 1) | ForEach-Object{
    # Convert the number to a base equal to the element count in operators. Use those values to represent the index of the operators array.
    $mathString = $formatString  -f @([string[]][char[]]((ConvertTo-Base -Number $_ -Base $operators.Count).PadLeft($range.count - 1,"0")) | ForEach-Object{$operators[[int]$_]})
    # Build an object that contains the result and the mathematical expression 
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Expression = $mathString
        Value = Invoke-Expression $mathString      
    }
    # Since this take a while try and give the user some semblance of progress. 
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing mathematical calculations" -Status "Please wait." -PercentComplete ($_ / $permutations * 100) -CurrentOperation "$([math]::Round($_ / $permutations * 100))% Completed."

    # Filter for whole number and only give group results
} | Where-Object{$_.Value -is [int32]} | Group-Object Value | Where-Object{$_.Count -ge $lowCountThreshold} | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

Comment: We need the source code...

Comment: I think putting your source code at the top would be good, but that's a suggestion.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally to find out what part of your code is slow, you would run it in a profiler. PowerShell however, unfortunately, doesn't have a profiler, so we have to use other means. There are various ways of finding the slow part.

You could put timing code in your code to measure how long the various parts take. The .NET [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) class might be helpful here.

Another easy way is to simply just chop out bits of your code until it speeds up. That's what I tried with your code.

The first thing I tried was to comment out the `Write-Progress`. That seemed like a likely candidate for being different in the ISE and in the console. When I did that, the code sped up instantly. So that seems to be the culprit.

All you have to do is call it less frequently. You could do something like this:

```
# Show progress bar. We don't call Write-Progress each time through the loop 
# because that is slow.
if ($i % 1000 -eq 0)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Performing mathematical calculations" `
        -Status "Please wait." -PercentComplete (100 * $i / $permutations) `
        -CurrentOperation "$([math]::Round(100 * $i / $permutations))% Completed."
}
```